# Line 4:13: 'React' is not defined no-undef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

When i want to create an element without JSX it shows me this error `'React' is not defined no-undef`. I am a beginner. I don't know what is the problem. Can anyone help

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

const app = React.createElement("h1", null, "Without JSX");  // Showing an error

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {app};
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

These messages are shown in VS code Terminal.

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
SyntaxError: E:\react_js_course\src\index.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (11:2)
Failed to compile.

src\App.js
  Line 4:13:  'React' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

Comment: `import React from 'react'`

Comment: well it's literally what it says, React isn't defined (cos you haven't imported it). `import React from 'react';`

Comment: Why don't you use JSX syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple points just based on the code you provided:

1. You are using JSX in your example: your `App` component returns JSX, so `React` should be in scope to do that.
2. You are explicitly using the React method `createElement` so `React` should be available **in this file**.

To fix both issues add `import React from 'react';` at the top of this file.

Answer (score 0):

import React from 'react' is required for writing code in JSX and alternative you use ES7 snippet which help to auto populate the code

[image]

Img-extension ss